# heap error after changing from new allocation to smartpointer

Tags: c++, winapi

```
extern "C" int __stdcall calcA(
  LPCSTR SerialNumber,
  double Diameter,
  int Design,
  int FoilSpacing,
  double RotorSpeed,
  double Altitude,
  double SupplyAirInletTemperature,
  double SupplyAirInletMoistureContent,
  double ExhaustAirInletTemperature,
  double ExhaustAirInletMoistureContent,
  double SupplyAirOutletFlow,
  double ExhaustAirInletFlow,
  double PressureDifference,
  bool PurgingSector,
  double* PowerTotal,
  double* PowerSensibel,
  double* TemperatureEfficiency,
  double* HumidityEfficiency,
  double* SupplyAirOutletTemperature,
  double* SupplyAirOutletMoistureContent,
  double* ExhaustAirOutletTemperature,
  double* ExhaustAirOutletMoistureContent,
  double* SupplyAirOutletVelocity,
  double* ExhaustAirInletVelocity,
  double* SupplyAirSidePressureDrop,
  double* ExhaustAirSidePressureDrop,
  double* HumidifyingDehumidifying,
  double* ExcessWater,
  double* ExhaustAirTransferRatio,
  double* OutdoorAirCorrectionFactor,
  bool* Frostrisk,
  double* CarryOverAirFlow)
{
  int returnValue = 0;

  if (NULL == SerialNumber)
  {
    returnValue = NULL_POINTER;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t newsize = strlen(SerialNumber) + 1; /* Including NULL */
    LPWSTR wcSerialNumber = new wchar_t[newsize];
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    if ((0 != mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcSerialNumber, newsize, SerialNumber, _TRUNCATE)) || (convertedChars != newsize))
    {
      returnValue = INVALID_STRING_CONVERSION;
    }

    if (0 == returnValue)
    {
      returnValue = calcW(wcSerialNumber,
                          Diameter,
                          Design,
                          FoilSpacing,
                          RotorSpeed,
                          Altitude,
                          SupplyAirInletTemperature,
                          SupplyAirInletMoistureContent,
                          ExhaustAirInletTemperature,
                          ExhaustAirInletMoistureContent,
                          SupplyAirOutletFlow,
                          ExhaustAirInletFlow,
                          PressureDifference,
                          PurgingSector,
                          PowerTotal,
                          PowerSensibel,
                          TemperatureEfficiency,
                          HumidityEfficiency,
                          SupplyAirOutletTemperature,
                          SupplyAirOutletMoistureContent,
                          ExhaustAirOutletTemperature,
                          ExhaustAirOutletMoistureContent,
                          SupplyAirOutletVelocity,
                          ExhaustAirInletVelocity,
                          SupplyAirSidePressureDrop,
                          ExhaustAirSidePressureDrop,
                          HumidifyingDehumidifying,
                          ExcessWater,
                          ExhaustAirTransferRatio,
                          OutdoorAirCorrectionFactor,
                          Frostrisk,
                          CarryOverAirFlow);
    }

    delete[] wcSerialNumber;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

To change this code to use smart pointers. My code look like this

```
extern "C" int __stdcall calcA(
  LPCSTR SerialNumber,
  double Diameter,
  int Design,
  int FoilSpacing,
  double RotorSpeed,
  double Altitude,
  double SupplyAirInletTemperature,
  double SupplyAirInletMoistureContent,
  double ExhaustAirInletTemperature,
  double ExhaustAirInletMoistureContent,
  double SupplyAirOutletFlow,
  double ExhaustAirInletFlow,
  double PressureDifference,
  bool PurgingSector,
  double* PowerTotal,
  double* PowerSensibel,
  double* TemperatureEfficiency,
  double* HumidityEfficiency,
  double* SupplyAirOutletTemperature,
  double* SupplyAirOutletMoistureContent,
  double* ExhaustAirOutletTemperature,
  double* ExhaustAirOutletMoistureContent,
  double* SupplyAirOutletVelocity,
  double* ExhaustAirInletVelocity,
  double* SupplyAirSidePressureDrop,
  double* ExhaustAirSidePressureDrop,
  double* HumidifyingDehumidifying,
  double* ExcessWater,
  double* ExhaustAirTransferRatio,
  double* OutdoorAirCorrectionFactor,
  bool* Frostrisk,
  double* CarryOverAirFlow)
{
  int returnValue = 0;

  if (NULL == SerialNumber)
  {
    returnValue = NULL_POINTER;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t newsize = strlen(SerialNumber) + 1; /* Including NULL */
    auto wcSerialNumber = make_unique<wchar_t>(newsize);
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    if ((0 != mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcSerialNumber.get(), newsize, SerialNumber, _TRUNCATE)) || (convertedChars != newsize))
    {
      returnValue = INVALID_STRING_CONVERSION;
    }

    if (0 == returnValue)
    {
      returnValue = calcW(wcSerialNumber.get(),
                          Diameter,
                          Design,
                          FoilSpacing,
                          RotorSpeed,
                          Altitude,
                          SupplyAirInletTemperature,
                          SupplyAirInletMoistureContent,
                          ExhaustAirInletTemperature,
                          ExhaustAirInletMoistureContent,
                          SupplyAirOutletFlow,
                          ExhaustAirInletFlow,
                          PressureDifference,
                          PurgingSector,
                          PowerTotal,
                          PowerSensibel,
                          TemperatureEfficiency,
                          HumidityEfficiency,
                          SupplyAirOutletTemperature,
                          SupplyAirOutletMoistureContent,
                          ExhaustAirOutletTemperature,
                          ExhaustAirOutletMoistureContent,
                          SupplyAirOutletVelocity,
                          ExhaustAirInletVelocity,
                          SupplyAirSidePressureDrop,
                          ExhaustAirSidePressureDrop,
                          HumidifyingDehumidifying,
                          ExcessWater,
                          ExhaustAirTransferRatio,
                          OutdoorAirCorrectionFactor,
                          Frostrisk,
                          CarryOverAirFlow);
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

The code compile but at run time i get _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData). Have a totally misunderstood smart pointers. The program is getting a heap error....

Comment: you converted a `wchar_t` array to a pointer to a single `wchar_t`.  They are not even close to the same thing here.

Comment: If you read [the documentation for std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), you'll see that the syntax for case 2 (allocating an array of objects) requires empty square brackets, as shown in the example at the bottom of the page: `/* Create a unique_ptr to an array of 5 elements */ std::unique_ptr<Vec3[]> v3 = std::make_unique<Vec3[]>(5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LPWSTR wcSerialNumber = new wchar_t[newsize];
auto wcSerialNumber = make_unique<wchar_t>(newsize);
```

Those two lines do very different things. The first dynamically allocates an array of `wchar_t`s with a number of elements equal to `newsize`. The second line dynamically allocates a *single* `wchar_t`, calling the constructor with `newsize` as an argument.

`std::unique_ptr` is not the best option in this case. Dynamic arrays are better replaced with `std::vector`. In your case, this might look like:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> wcSerialNumber (newsize);
```

Then instead of calling `wcSerialNumber.get()`, call `wcSerialNumber.data()`.

Answer (score 2):

`make_unique<wchar_t>(newsize)` allocates memory for a single `wchar_t` only, what you need is `make_unique<wchar_t[]>(newsize)`